# Hover effect works with Firefox but no other browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

Here is my code:

```
.post .entry a:hover{

 opacity: 0.5;

 transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 }
```

I'm not sure as to why this wont work with Chrome/IE/Safari. It is working fine with Firefox.

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Without a better example, I made a quick fiddle. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox for me. http://jsfiddle.net/hgeVd/

Comment: Here is my example: http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/projects-2

Comment: Which IE version are you having problems with? Hit F12. Go to the Console tab. Fix all the errors that it points out.

Comment: rule 1: put the unprefixed version last, after the prefixed styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're floating the images inside of the links. Move the float to elements that are on the same level as each other.

Also, replace your paragraph tags with div tags. Paragraphs are for text, not layout.